# LaTeX+gnuplot contours disappearing

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdftex, gnuplot

I have been generating my plots directly in my .tex files for a while. This all works fine if I open the pdf generated by pdflatex, however, I have noticed that if I print (hardcopy) or just export that pdf to a new one, all my contours disappear (the axis are still there).

The code I use is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=0.8\textwidth,
height=0.33\textwidth,
axis equal,
view={0}{90},
colormap/hot2,
colorbar,
colorbar style={
scale only axis,
yticklabel style={
align=right,
/pgf/number format/.cd,
fixed,
try min ticks=6
}}
]
\addplot3[raw gnuplot,surf,shader=interp]
gnuplot[id={surf}]{
set parametric;
set pm3d;
splot 'data/field/tkemean.dat' u 1:2:(($3)/2.0)
};                
\fill [gray, thick] (axis cs:-0.5,0.0) rectangle (axis cs:0.5,0.5);
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Both the colorbar and the rectangle "survive" the print, but the contour disappears.

Anyone has come across this issue?

Comment: After creating the PDF there is nothing related to the source anymore. Your printer might have a quirk instead.

Comment: @percusse well that was my first thought, but it will also happen if I use a virtual printer to export the document. I have tried with multiple printers and on mac, windows and linux computers, all have the same issue. here's the example if you want to try:

original image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/25n99kva1d790ko/Figure14_original.pdf?dl=0
printed to a new pdf: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6bmwe7qlmiyyjd/Figure14_printed.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Please edit your question so that it includes a complete example, from `\begin{document}` to `\end{document}`. This will make it easier for other users to help you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the data files are no longer available and thus it is very unlikely that the question can be solved.

Comment: I have "fixed" this by running the chain (on a Mac):

pdf2ps ps2eps epstopdf

But no clue what was causing the problem...